# Java Generic Csv String to Enum List

Tags: java, generics, enums

I would like to genericly convert String in csv form to List of enum.
However java won't recognise the generic enum type.

I'm using Guava and can't use Java 8.

Any idea ?

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> getEnumList(String csvLine) {
    List<String> csvList = Arrays.asList(csvLine.split(","));

    Function<String, E> enumList = new Function<String, E>() {
       @Override
       public E apply(String csvStr) {
          return Enum.valueOf(E.class, csvStr);
       }
    };

    return Lists.transform(csvList, enumList);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the `Class<E>`, because `E` will be erased (and replaced with something specific at Runtime).

Something like:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> getEnumList(String csvLine, Class<E> clazz) {
    List<String> csvList = Arrays.asList(csvLine.split(","));

    Function<String, E> enumList = new Function<String, E>() {
       @Override
       public E apply(String csvStr) {
          return Enum.valueOf(clazz, "");
       }
    };

    return Lists.transform(csvList, enumList);
}
```

As a side note, I guess you have to replace the empty string `""` with `csvStr`, otherwise the `csvStr` parameter doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Indeed, i forgot to change "" to strCsv.